# SQL SERVER mito sobre o SELECT INTO e bloqueios no tempdb

Tags: sql-server, tabela-temporária, ddl

Ultimamente tenho estudado bastante sobre banco de dados e tudo mais. Hoje, realizando um verificação de rotina nos processos da instância do SQL Server verifiquei que uma instrução que estava executando em um banco estava bloqueando a execução em outro banco de dados. Realizando verificações nas consultas que estavam sendo executadas naquele momento, vi que não havia uma *ligação direta* entre as consultas, suas estruturas são parecidas com estas:

**Consulta sendo executada no banco A:**

```
SELECT ... INTO #tempA /*consultas de tabelas no banco A apenas*/
```

**Consulta sendo executada no banco B:**

```
SELECT ... INTO #tempB /*consultas de tabelas no banco B apenas*/
```

Vendo isto, verifiquei que a unica parte em que as consultas se assemelham é na criação da tabela *temporária* junto ao select em `SELECT ... INTO #tmp` resolvi pesquisar sobre isso, encontrei alguns artigos, porém, todos me deixaram com dúvidas sobre a vericidade de minha conclusão.

[SQL Server SELECT INTO and Blocking With Temp Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302670/sql-server-select-into-and-blocking-with-temp-tables)

[SQL Server lock issues when using a DDL (including SELECT INTO) clause in long running transactions](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-lock-issues-when-using-a-ddl-including-select-into-clause-in-long-running-transactions/)

Nestes dois artigos que tomei como exemplo, podem se verificar respostas e comentários totalmente conflitantes como:

**Originais**

> Does select ... into #temp block something for the duration of the stored procedure containing the select? Hell no. Just reading that claim and I burst into laugh.
>
> Does select ... into #temp block something for the duration of the select? Not really.
>
> Fortunately, it was only a problem for SQL 6.5. It was fixed in 7.0 and later.

**Traduções**

> O select ... into #temp bloqueia algo pela duração do procedimento armazenado que contém o select? De jeito nenhum. Apenas lendo essa afirmação e eu comecei a rir.
>
> O select ... into #temp bloqueia algo pela duração do select? Na verdade não.
>
> Felizmente, foi apenas um problema para o SQL 6.5. Foi corrigido no 7.0 e posterior.

**Citações foram retiradas de vários usuários.

Enquanto no segundo link, em suas conclusões é dito o seguinte:

**Original**

> DDL (including SELECT INTO) statements containing long-running
> explicit transactions, should be avoided if possible because it
> creates exclusive locks on row(s) in system tables for the duration of
> the transaction.
>
> This might not cause detrimental effects, but often it misleads DBAs
> to think there was a network connectivity or SQL Server resource
> issue. If the code is not well written, you may encounter lock request
> timeouts when performing typical administrative tasks such as checking
> database properties from SSMS. In actuality, you are just experiencing
> typical locks and blocks on row(s) in system tables.

**Tradução**

> Instruções DDL (incluindo SELECT INTO) contendo transações explícitas
> de execução longa devem ser evitadas, se possível, porque cria
> bloqueios exclusivos na (s) linha (s) nas tabelas do sistema pela
> duração da transação.
>
> Isso pode não causar efeitos prejudiciais, mas muitas vezes engana os
> DBAs a pensar que havia um problema de conectividade de rede ou de
> recurso do SQL Server. Se o código não estiver bem escrito, você
> poderá encontrar tempos limite de solicitação de bloqueio ao executar
> tarefas administrativas típicas, como verificar propriedades do banco
> de dados do SSMS. Na realidade, você está experimentando bloqueios e
> blocos típicos em linhas nas tabelas do sistema.

Desculpe por me estender na pergunta, porém, gostaria de saber qual está correto? Realmente DDL´s como SELECT ... INTO #temp causam bloqueios no tempdb? Qual dos links está mais correto? Há algum local onde eu possa pesquisar mais sobre tal assunto? Há alguma forma de testar as argumentações dos envolvidos nos links acima?

Desde já, Agradeço.

P.S: Estou utilizando o SQL Server 12.0, mais conhecido como SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TEMPDB** É uma base de dados do system e toda vez que você usa tabelas temporárias (#MyTempTableExample) elas são criadas nessa base de dados (não com esse nome porém pq várias sessões podem estar usando esse mesmo nome, se vc procurar vai ver que o nome real é algo bem estranho).
Note que a `tempdb` é usada o tempo todo pela engine, especialmente para operações que processam muitos dados onde a `tempdb` é usado como uma forma de "memória" auxiliar.

Aqui vou só dar um rápido overview sobre alguns problemas relacionados com a sua questão.

1) Muito comum um bloqueio de recursos físicos, memória e especialmente IO. Note que ao dar um insert de milhões de registros vc estará usando massivamente o acesso a disco (não só pelos dados mas pelos índices e outras estruturas e tb pelo log). Então pode haver ai um gargalo de hardware.

2) O segundo link que vc postou mostra um artigo sobre um problema testado no SQL Server 2016 (o primeiro link fala de um problema semelhante mas que ocorria em uma versão muito antiga e que foi corrigido muitos anos atrás). Nesse link é demonstrado que ao criar e popular sua tabela temporária algumas tabelas de sistema ficam bloqueadas, em especial a `[sys].[sysrscols]`. Pessoalmente eu não testei mas faz sentido pq quando vc cria objetos (tabelas, colunas, etc) esses objetos ficam catalogados nessas tabelas.
Note que é interessante fazer esse teste no seu sistema para avaliar se isso ocorre.

3) A ainda outras considerações sobre a `tempdb` especialmente quando você usa níveis de isolamento `snapshot` que utiliza a `tempdb` p/ guardar versões de seus dados.

4) Finalmente o uso de tabelas temporárias pode ser muitas vezes substituído por variáveis de tabela. Note porém que depende de caso a caso. Como as variáveis (normalmente) ficam em memória elas tendem a ser mais performática quando elas são pequenas. Por experiência as tabelas temporárias são melhores quando vc está populando-as com muitos dados (isso é devido à quantidade de memória alocada para as variáveis de tabela que quando estoura começa a usar a `tempdb` mas com um overhead que piora muito a performance dessas variáveis.).

**Conclusão**

Tabelas temporárias são uma ferramenta importante do dia-a-adia mas como todas as ferramentas do SQL-SERVER estão sujeitas a problemas em alguns cenários específicos e devem ser usadas com cuidado.

Então para determinar se seu `SQL INTO` nessas tabelas temporárias está tendo um impacto negativo em performance vc vai ter que checar se o problema é realmente esse, um bom ponto de partida é esse segundo link que vc postou.

Comment: Ótima explicação... Não sabia deste caso do sysrcols, mas realmente, faz todo o sentido...